# How create two rectangles under header

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm new about wordpress but I want put two rectangles under the header of my page where every rectangles in linked at another page. How I can do this? what I must use to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Set two div with same width in header.php and under the div give `<a>` attribute for redirection.

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answer said put these in header.php and insert in the divs whatever you want.

```
<style>
.rect{
     display:inline-block;
     vertical-align:top;
     border:solid 1px black;
     width:20px;
     height:30px;
 }
</style>


<div class='rect_cont'>
   <div class='rect'></div>
   <div class='rect'></div>
</div>
```